# Appending blocks of data to an Array in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a 60 year monthly cash flow in a spreadsheet and iterate through 1,000+ cases in a for loop. I want to store these cash flows in an array. It's much faster to grab an entire range at once and store it in the array than going cell by cell. Currently I have the following code grabbing the data within then loop:

```
With ActiveSheet
     CF_Arr(i, 1) = .Range(.Cells(StartRow, StartCol), .Cells(EndRow, EndCol))
End With
```

The issue with this is that it increases the dimensions of the array. I would rather append the cash flows at the end of the array. For example, if CF_Arr = [x x x] and I add another block of data I want it to look like CF_Arr = [x x x x x x], not CF_Arr = [[x x x], [x x x]]. When it looks like the latter and you want to write it back to a sheet you have to iterate through it rather than write it all at once using something like:

```
With ActiveSheet
     .Range(.Cells((i - 1) * (EndRow - StartRow + 1) + 2, 1), _
     .Cells(i * (EndRow - StartRow + 1) + 2, EndCol - 
     StartCol)).Value2 = cashFlow(i, 1)
end with
```

Comment: Have you considered looping through the [xxx],[xxx] array and transferring it to a 2nd array so that its [xxxxxx] and then pasting it? It should still be pretty quick since it's between arrays.

Comment: You could write an `AppendArray()` method which would do this  - create a third array large enough to hold both arrays, and then write them both into it.  Should be pretty fast.

Comment: The cash flow is 68 columns and 733 rows, but could have more columns if we need to break out more line items. So with 1,000 cases that is 733,000 rows x 68 columns or ~50 million unique elements to loop through. I'd like to avoid looping through that much data if I can.

Comment: You can iterate through a 2d array by going top to bottom in the first column, then top to bottom in the second column, and repeat. You would only need to add a little bit of index calculations.

Comment: What do you mean "1000 cases"? (A sample of your data would've been helpful.) What is this For loop you're talking about? (See [mcve].)  Also are you aware you can place the entire 68x733 cells into an array with one short line of code?

Comment: @ashleedawg Essentially there will be 1,000 distinct cash flows. Each cash flow is around 68 columns and 733 rows. The for loop iterates through the different scenarios to be run through the cash flow. After each iteration I grab the entire cash flow at once and store it in a variant array, CF_Arr(i, 1). The first block of code I show above puts the entire 68x733 cells into the array at once. So after each iteration the dimension of the array increases with i. I would like to string the cash flows together such that [[x x x][x x x]] is instead [x x x x x x].